# Gstreamer hlssink not working properly with opencv

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, opencv3.0

I am trying to stream an HLS video using GStreamer in OpenCV.

This is my OpenCV writer:

```
writer.open("appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! queue ! hlssink target-duration=2 playlist-length=10 ", 0, fps, cv::Size(width, height), true);
```

The output of this writer is very fluttered. Here is the screenshot of the output.
[image]

While this command streams the video perfectly.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink target-duration=1 playlist-length=12
```

Am I doing something wrong?

(I am using OpenCV 3.4.0)